# Can we structure a website in groups using Django framework or rails(groups like admin, moderators,helpers,users,etc)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, laravel

I am trying to make a site where i can divide the site into **different member categories like admin,moderators,helpers,users,etc** *with their own functionalities* ... I have once used the **Django** framework, so my question is can i be able to do this task also using Django again, i mean, can Django fulfill this task's requirements easily so i may not need to roam to other languages or frameworks for this particular task?

P.S.: I know php(framework like **laravel** or others)can do this task but i was just trying to implement Django since i have used it once already. OR do you recommend frameworks like **Rails**(i have heard a lot about it specifically on field of web-development,can it do this task). OR Anyone please tell me which should i use ?

**I am in a lot of dilemma in choosing among these three.**

Regards,

**Note: I have edited the whole description.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Django authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/#user-authentication-in-django) has groups.

Users can be assigned to groups and permissions can be added to groups (giving all the users of the group the set of permissions which is assigned to the group).

Comment: hello there ... can we perform this all task of making some users admins, someone as mods , someone as users or any other groups everywhere ... i am not talking only about forum i am talking about the entire site. I am impressed with specifically the torrent site's structuring paradigm ... where admins have total ownership and mods have a bit less than that admins but can edit,demote threads and users,etc-etc hope u understand what i am saying

Comment: Thanks for your useful response ...